# What is this old movie that featured round, flat creatures that killed by touch?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember that I watched this movie as a kid, probably in the late 70's - early 80's.  I think it was a black and white movie.  I believe the story revolved around an outbreak of creatures that were roughly 1-2 feet in diameter, would cling to walls and ceilings, and their touch would kill.

They reminded me very much of some aliens from an old Star Trek: TOS episode, but these may have been lab created rather than aliens.

I do remember there was one scene where some of the main characters were trying to move through a house with these creatures covering just about every surface.  Being an old movie, there wasn't much in the way of special effects for the creatures.  From what I remember they looked pretty much like pieces of plastic, and they may have quivered slightly.  I don't remember for sure if they were mobile, but I believe they could either drop from heights or crawl extremely slowly.

Comment: FYI, the episode you're thinking of is [Operation -- Annihilate!](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Operation_--_Annihilate!)

Comment: @Keith yep! That's the ST episode I was thinking of.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be "[Without Warning](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081764/)"?

It had disc like aliens that clung to people and killed them. Here's a video:

Comment: Good shot of the alien if you move to 31m30s

Comment: The movie I'm thinking of is much older than that, but good find!

Answer (score 4):

This is a long shot, but maybe you're thinking of ["The Brain Eaters"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051432/)?

I found a [description with a few images](http://mansplat.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/non-zombie-brain-eaters/), and a [much longer plot summary (also with some images)](http://www.braineater.com/braineaters.html).

Comment: That looks and sounds very close to what I remember.  Neither of the sources you listed mention the house scene, but it is entirely possible that I'm conflating two or more movies.

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of the low-budget Roger Corman horror movie "It Conquered the World" (with Peter Graves!) or its even lower-budget remake, "Zontar: The Thing From Venus":  an alien master-mind from another world tries to conquer the world with vaguely bat-like "mind-control pods", and the only thing that can stop him is square-jawed wooden scientist action.

Comment: Hrm... I'm not sure those are it, but they certainly seem possible matches.  Thanks!

Comment: https://wifflegif.com/tags/457889-island-of-terror-gifs